# Best method of applying multiple functions over similar structured df's in a list?

Tags: r, purrr, sapply

I have a list object called `Profile_list` combining multiple df's, all with the same columns (but different number of rows):

```
> summary(Profile_list)
            Length Class      Mode
Profile_19  26     data.frame list
Profile_20  26     data.frame list
Profile_21  26     data.frame list
Profile_40  26     data.frame list
Profile_41  26     data.frame list
Profile_84  26     data.frame list
Profile_92  26     data.frame list
Profile_95  26     data.frame list
Profile_98  26     data.frame list
Profile_106 26     data.frame list
Profile_135 26     data.frame list
Profile_139 26     data.frame list
```

I want to be able to apply the `dplyr::select` function to select columns `Col_A` and `Col_B`, then to find `unique` combinations of these two extracted columns of each df, then assign these results to a new list with the same names of the dfs,  `Profile_list_unique_indicators`. What would be the best wayof achieving this?

Comment: What do you mean by "`unique` combinations of these two"? Can you share an example of expected output in a single `data.frame`?

Comment: @RLave `mpg %>% select(fl, class) %>% group_by(fl, class) %>% unique()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution with `purrr`, and the use of `map` (as long as the names of the columns are the same across all `data.frames`):

```
purrr::map(my_list, function(x) {
  x %>%  select(a, b) %>% group_by(a, b) %>% unique()
})
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# # Groups:   a, b [3]
#       a     b
# <dbl> <int>
# 1     2     1
# 2     2     2
# 3     2     3
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# # Groups:   a, b [3]
#       a     b
# <dbl> <int>
# 1     1     4
# 2     1     5
# 3     1     6
```

But I don't see the difference from simply use `distinct`:

```
purrr::map(my_list, function(x) {
     x %>%  select(a, b) %>% distinct(a, b)
})
# [[1]]
#   a b
# 1 2 1
# 2 2 2
# 3 2 3
# 
# [[2]]
#   a b
# 1 1 4
# 2 1 5
# 3 1 6
```

Fake data:

```
data <- data.frame(a = rep(2, 4), b = rep(1:3, 4))
data2 <- data.frame(a = rep(1, 4), b = rep(4:6, 4))

my_list <- list(data, data2)
my_list
# [[1]]
#    a b
# 1  2 1
# 2  2 2
# 3  2 3
# 4  2 1
# 5  2 2
# 6  2 3
# 7  2 1
# 8  2 2
# 9  2 3
# 10 2 1
# 11 2 2
# 12 2 3
# 
# [[2]]
#    a b
# 1  1 4
# 2  1 5
# 3  1 6
# 4  1 4
# 5  1 5
# 6  1 6
# 7  1 4
# 8  1 5
# 9  1 6
# 10 1 4
# 11 1 5
# 12 1 6
```